# How can I be getting a NullException error if I'm verifying the two items are NOT null?

Tags: android, listadapter

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
```

I keep getting this error when executing this code:

```
if (listView != null && adapter != null) {
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Here's the full stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:337)                                                                                            
at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:491)
at com.themorrisonagency.gcocommuter.RideFragmentPage.setUserVisibleHint(RideFragmentPage.java:94)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:157)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1270)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1120)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:277)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5491)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Here is where I'm initializing the adapter:

```
public RideMatchesAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Ride> objects)   
{
   super(context, resource, objects);
   if (objects != null) {
       activityContext = context;
       layoutResource = resource;
       this.rideList = objects;
       final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() /1024);
       final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
   } else {
       Log.e(TAG, "objects cannot be null");
   }
}
```

Also tried checking if my internal list is null. Still throwing the exception:

```
public int getCount(){
    if(this.rideList != null){
        return this.rideList.size();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: null reference exception is not happening exactly there unless you're running old code. Do you have a stacktrace? It says something about `java.util.List.size()`. Is adapter a custom one?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This if statement is placed in the setUserVisibleHint method.

Comment: You should do the null check before creating an object of `RideMatchesAdapter`. Create that object and set that adapter to your listview only if the `List<Ride>` is not null.

Comment: I feel like using the setUserVisibleHint is a hacky way to do this.  I only have 3 pages that hold under 10 entries. Is there a way I could load these pages once and keep them from getting destroyed?  Then I wouldn't need to worry about reloading.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the single line of stack-trace you have added, my bet is that your `NullPointerException` is happening inside your Adapter code. Probably in this method :

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemsList.size();// Maybe your itemsList is null.
}
```

If you are using `ArrayAdapter` then you are not initialising your adapter properly. You need to pass a non-null list to your `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: I don't have a getItemCount() method, but I do have a getCount() method that returns my internal list size. I'm checking if list is null before returning.

Comment: @dawoodman71 Can you post the code where you are initialising your `adapter` object?

Comment: `public RideMatchesAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Ride> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        if (objects != null) {
            activityContext = context;
            layoutResource = resource;
            this.rideList = objects;
            final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
            final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "objects cannot be null");
        }
     }`

That looks horrible . . . I'm going to post this in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think exception coming from the adapter. Check adapter code for where retrieving data list size.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping walk through this process. While none of the suggestion actually fixed my issue I appreciate your help!

My problem was actually cause by the adapter != null, but, for some reason, I needed to recreate the adapter. I assumed that it would stay put since the Fragment had not been destroyed.

In my setUserVisibleHint:

```
if (isVisibleToUser) {
        ((RidesActivity) getContext()).setIndicator(POSITION);
        if (fragmentLoaded) {
            if (GACommuter.rideMatches == null) {
                ((RidesActivity) getContext()).loadData();
            } else if(listView != null) {
                adapter = new RideMatchesAdapter(this.getContext(),  R.layout.ride_match, GACommuter.rideMatches);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    }
```